# How to include post count in this "get_tags" snippet

Tags: tags, query, array

Can anyone tell me how I can show a post count in this code snippet?

```
<?php $tags = get_tags();
   if ($tags) {
   foreach ($tags as $tag) {
   echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tag->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tag->name.'</a> </li> ';
   }
};?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where exactly? 
example below is for the count getting shown in brackets after the tag name, outside the link:

```
<?php 
$tags = get_tags();    
  if ($tags) {    
  foreach ($tags as $tag) {    
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tag->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tag->name.'</a> ('.$tag->count.') </li> ';    
  } 
  };
?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags